# Is there a good trick for instantiating a subclass with an instance of its superclass?

Tags: inheritance, composition

Preferably in Java, is there a good way to instantiate a subclass from an instance of a superclass?

Say I have ClassB which subclasses ClassA, here is the constructor for ClassA:

```
 public ClassA(){


  }
```

I want to do something like:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{

     public ClassB(ClassA aClassA){

       super(aClassA);

    }
}
```

Is there any way to easily get an instance of a subclass from an instance of the superclass, especially when the subclass might only have one extra field than the superclass, and therefore there isn't much difference between them?

For instance,

ClassA a = new ClassA();

ClassB b = a;

(the compiler is going to want me to do this:  `ClassB b = (ClassB)a;` ... which is not going to work.)

How do I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This is symptomatic of bad problem modeling and/or OO design. I recommend thinking a little harder in the problem that is leading you to that solution...

Comment: I agree, mostly. But I still think it should be a feature of Java to create at least part of a subclass from a superclass. If you have a Mammal you should be able to create a Tiger, you just need a little bit of extra information. Imagine if a superclass contained ALL of the information that a subclass needed, and a subclass was just a slice of the information in the superclass. In that way, it should be at least possible to create a subclass FROM a superclass.

Comment: many times, I feel like it would be a worthy Object Oriented goal to hide information in a subclass, so in that case, the subclass would contain identical info, but would simply hide information.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to easily get an instance of a subclass from an instance of the superclass

No , the superclass instance doesn't contain the subclass instance . What you are trying to do is to cast the object referenced by superclass type reference variable to an object of subclass.

```
ClassB b = (ClassB)a;
```

It is dangerous , as it may fail if `a` actually didn't refer to an instance of `ClassB` at run time.

Remember all instances of `ClassB` are instanceof `ClassA` , but the reverse is not true.

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve , may be look at [Abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** possible to cast an Instance of `ClassA` into the subclass `ClassB`.

Think of it like this:

```
class A{

   int a;
}

class B extends A{
   long b;
}


A a = new A(); //creating instance of super class. This instance will not have `b`

boolean result = a instanceof B; //the result will be false but if you cast ignoring that

B b = (B)a; //Will throw a CLASS CAST EXCEPTION at runtime
```

You can do this:

```
A b = new B();

B bb = (B)b;
```

All instances of `B` are instances of `A` too but inverse is not possible . You can check it using `instanceof`.

Comment: Thanks narendra for explaining this perfectly. But personally I think there should be a way to do this in java. But I agree that it is not possible.

Comment: If there is a class `Book` and it has child class `HardboundBook`, then it is safe to say that a `HardboundBook` will also be a `Book`. But if the instance is of `Book`, then you cannot say it is a `HardboundBook`. So logically too it is not possible.

Comment: Yes I agree...but if you have a book to start with, it should be easier to create a hardboundbook then if you start with nothing...right? Imagine you had nothing in your left hand and a book in your right hand, which would you prefer in order to create a hardboundbook? Clearly the answer is a book, not nothing at all.

Comment: Therefore, java should provide a way to help you instantiate a subclass from a superclass, I believe it may be called a wrapper class.